# Python: transform a list of lists of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose I have a data structure as follows:

```
[[ tuple11,
   tuple12,
   ... ],
 [ tuple21,
   tuple22,
   ... ],
 ...]
```

That is, the outer list can have any number of elements and each element (list) can contain any number of elements (tuples). How can I transform it to:

```
[[ tuple11,
   tuple21,
   ... ],
 [ tuple12,
   tuple22,
   ... ],
 ... ]
```

I have the following solution working for two elements in the outer list, but I cannot figure out how to generalise it:

```
map(lambda x, y: [x, y], *the_list)
```

**Added:**

Just to add some more detail, each of the tuples above is in fact a tuple of two `np.array`s.

If I start out with the following data structure:

```
[[(array([111, 111]), array([121, 121])),
  (array([112, 112]), array([122, 122])),
  (array([131, 131]), array([141, 141])),
  (array([132, 132]), array([142, 142]))],
 [(array([211, 211]), array([221, 221])),
  (array([212, 212]), array([222, 222])),
  (array([231, 231]), array([241, 241])),
  (array([232, 232]), array([242, 242]))]]
```

I need to turn this into:

```
[[(array([111, 111]), array([121, 121])),
  (array([211, 211]), array([221, 221]))],
 [(array([112, 112]), array([122, 122])),
  (array([212, 212]), array([222, 222]))],
 [(array([131, 131]), array([141, 141])),
  (array([231, 231]), array([241, 241]))],
 [(array([132, 132]), array([142, 142])),
  (array([232, 232]), array([242, 242]))]]
```

Note that the arrays are not always 1✕2 but 1✕N in general for any positive N. There are always two arrays in each tuple but any number of tuples in each inner list and any number of these inner lists in the outer list.

I am quite used to juggling NumPy arrays, but I have very little experience with the native lists, tuples etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the columns, so you can use `zip` function :

```
zip(*main_list)
```

But since it returns the columns in tuple format if you only want list you can use `map` to convert them to list :

```
map(list,zip(*main_list))
```

Demo:

```
>>> main_list=[[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]]
>>> zip(*main_list)
[((1, 2), (5, 6)), ((3, 4), (7, 8))]
```

And with your example :

```
>>> main_list=[[(np.array([111, 111]), np.array([121, 121])),
...   (np.array([112, 112]), np.array([122, 122])),
...   (np.array([131, 131]), np.array([141, 141])),
...   (np.array([132, 132]), np.array([142, 142]))],
...  [(np.array([211, 211]), np.array([221, 221])),
...   (np.array([212, 212]), np.array([222, 222])),
...   (np.array([231, 231]), np.array([241, 241])),
...   (np.array([232, 232]), np.array([242, 242]))]]
>>> 
>>> zip(*main_list)
[((array([111, 111]), array([121, 121])), (array([211, 211]), array([221, 221]))), 
((array([112, 112]), array([122, 122])), (array([212, 212]), array([222, 222]))), 
((array([131, 131]), array([141, 141])), (array([231, 231]), array([241, 241]))), 
((array([132, 132]), array([142, 142])), (array([232, 232]), array([242, 242])))]
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems there is a caveat here and your answer does not work in my particular case. Each of my `tuple11` etc. is in fact a tuple of two 1x2 `np.array`'s and apparently your approach ends up zipping those arrays together into 2x2 `np.array`'s. I am adding more info to the question to clarify this...

Comment: @ThomasArildsen It doesn't makes any difference, check the edit.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It turns out I accidentally tested your approach on another data structure I had in my workspace, with a slightly different layout. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution. I don't consider it elegant but at least it seems to work. Let's call the original list of lists of tuples `main_list` and the transformed list of lists of tuples `new_list`:

```
def transform_coeff_struct(main_list):

    new_list = []
    for ii, inner_list in enumerate(main_list):
        for jj, some_tuple in enumerate(inner_list):
            if ii==0:
                new_list.append([some_tuple,])
            else:
                new_list[jj].append(some_tuple)
    return new_list
```